# Publish MDCS as Web Tool: broken project data source

Tags: arcgis-pro, geoprocessing-service, mosaic-dataset

I am trying to publish a Python script as a web tool, where a Mosaic Dataset is created via MDCS (Mosaic Dataset Configuration Script).  It flags `00068 Script SCRIPT_NAME contains broken project data source: /Footprint` and
`24046 tool calculate field cannot use VB expressions for services`.

[image: ![enter image description here]

I am using the MDCS folders as downloaded from Github. The only modification I made is copying some scripts from subfolders to the main scripts folder. I have ctrl+F-searched all the sripts and did not find /Footprints.
I was able to successfully publish and run a script tool that creates a mosaic dataset with the Arcpy command.

What could this be?

I think it should be possible because of this [video](https://mediaspace.esri.com/meia/t/1_q98qok22) (23:14).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was because there is a "/Footprint" string in the solutionsLib.py file in the scripts folder of the MDCS directory. My workaround for now is that I commented out the function containing "/Footprints".

```
mlayerJoin = arcpy.AddJoin_management(
                    mlayer + "/Footprint",
                    self.getProcessInfoValue(processKey, 'input_join_field', index),
                    joinTable,
                    self.getProcessInfoValue(processKey, 'target_join_field', index),
                    "KEEP_ALL"
                )
```

It would be nice to know what the actual problem is here, or if it's really just kind of a bug? I had to import solutionsLib in my tool script, because otherwise it would complain about it not existing (because it is imported in the MDCS.py). I don't really understand why it is not imported there without problems, as the files are in the same directory.